# Jquery : Creating Dynamic Select list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i am creating a select list dynamically where user can add options after adding select list. Below is my code

```
 <script type="text/html" id="select_field">
       <div class='row'>
           <div class='col-md-3'><label>Select list name</label>
              <div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control select_name'></div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for=""></label>
                 <select name=""  class="form-control select-list" ></select>
            </div>
           <div class="append_list"></div>
          <a  class="btn btn-primary pull-right add_values">Add Values</a>
     </div>
 </script>
```

**JS:**

Below JS adds an text field with 2 buttons  option to add / remove field to the select list

```
$form_holder.on('click','.add_values', e => {
            var html  = "<div class='clearfix'></div>" +
                "<div class='col-md-4'><input type='text' class='form-control add_select_option' name='add_value' ><br>" +
                "<a class='add_option btn btn-default' value='Add' >Add</a>" +
                "<a class='remove_option btn btn-danger'  value='Remove'  >Remove</a><br></div>";
            let $target = $(e.target);
            let $value= e.target.value;
            let $div = $target.closest('.row').find('.append_list');
            $div.append(html);

        });
```

Below Code adds an option to the select list :

```
  $form_holder.on('click','.add_option', e => {
            let $target = $(e.target);
            console.log($target);
            let $value= e.target.value;
            let $value_toadd = $target.closest('.col-md-4').find('.form-control').val();
            console.log($value_toadd);
            let $select_list = $target.closest('.row').find('.select-list');
            $($select_list).append($('<option>', {
                value: $value_toadd,
                text: $value_toadd
            }));

        });
```

Now values are added successfully , but my problem is that ::

if I have added value using one text field and click on **add**  button again it embeds new value to the select list using the same text field, how do i uniquely identify each of the text fields while adding entries to select list , please advise .

I also have to use same unique value to remove the entry from the select list

Comment: difficult to see the problem without testing (for me), could you show a functional sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can give custom attribute to your inputs i.e : `data-id` . Then , whenever user click on `add` button check if the custom attr is already present in one of the option of select if yes show some message else add new data to selects .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var $form_holder = $("form")
$form_holder.on('click', '.add_values', e => {
  let $target = $(e.target);
  let $value = e.target.value;
  let $div = $target.closest('.row').find('.append_list');
  //add custom attr
  var html = "<div class='clearfix'></div>" +
    "<div class='col-md-4'><input type='text' class='form-control add_select_option' name='add_value' data-id='" + $div.find(".col-md-4").length + "'><br>" +
    "<a class='add_option btn btn-default' value='Add' >Add</a>" +
    "<a class='remove_option btn btn-danger'  value='Remove'  >Remove</a><br></div>";
  $div.append(html);

});

$form_holder.on('click', '.add_option', e => {
  let $target = $(e.target);
  let $value = e.target.value;
  var data_id = $target.closest('.col-md-4').find('.form-control').data('id'); //get custom attr added
  let $value_toadd = $target.closest('.col-md-4').find('.form-control').val();
  let $select_list = $target.closest('.row').find('.select-list');
  //check if select doesn't have that data-id
  if ($select_list.find("option[data_value=" + data_id + "]").length <= 0) {
    //then only add
    $($select_list).append($('<option>', {
      data_value: data_id,
      value: $value_toadd,
      text: $value_toadd
    }));
  } else {

    console.log(" already there ")
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-3'><label>Select list name</label>
      <div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control select_name'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for=""></label>
      <select name="" class="form-control select-list"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="append_list"></div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add_values">Add Values</a>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: hi , Thanks for your reply this works not to enter the data , how about deleting or updating record by loop ?

Comment: you can get attribute of remove button click near input box and then using that value you can delete same option from your nearest select-box .